# ¿Cómo hago un autocomplete si genero el input dinámicamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocompletar, autocomplete

### Generación de inputs

Tengo esta función en la cual dependiendo del valor de select genero inputs, el caso es que en el input con id 'placa' necesito hacerle un autocomplete para rellenar los demás inputs ('marca','modelo' y 'tipo'), pero mi error es que no lo hace.

```
$('#select_transporte').on('change', function (){
            $('#div_transporte').empty();
            switch($('#select_transporte').val()){
                case "0":
                $('#div_transporte').html("<div class='form-row'>"+
                            "<div class='form-group col-md-3'>"+
                                "<label for='inputCity'>Placas</label> "+
                                "<input id='placa' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Ingrese la placa' required>"+
                            "</div>"+
                            "<div class='form-group col-md-3'>"+
                                "<label for='inputState'>Marca</label>"+
                                "<input id='marca' type='text' class='form-control' readonly>"+
                            "</div>"+
                            "<div class='form-group col-md-3'>"+
                                "<label for='inputState'>Modelo</label>"+
                                "<input id='modelo' type='text' class='form-control' readonly>"+
                            "</div>"+
                            "<div class='form-group col-md-3'>"+
                                "<label for='inputState'>Tipo</label>"+
                                "<input id='tipo' type='text' class='form-control' readonly>"+
                            "</div>"+
                            "<input type='text' style='visibility: hidden;' id='idVehiculo'>"+
                        "</div>");
                    break;
                case "7":
                    $('#div_transporte').html("<div class='form-group row'>"+
                        "<label for='inputEmail3' class='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>Especifica</label>"+
                            "<div class='col-sm-10'>"+
                                "<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Especifica el vehiculo' required>"+
                            "</div>"+
                        "</div><br>");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
```

### Función autocomplete

```
$('#placa').autocomplete({
    source:function(request,response){
        console.log("Entre");
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{route('AjaxAlianza.getVehiculo')}}",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType:'json',
            data:{
                term:request.term
            },
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                response(data)
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#idVehiculo').val(ui.item.idVehiculo);
        $('#marca').val(ui.item.marcaVehi);
        $('#modelo').val(ui.item.modeloVehi);
        $('#tipo').val(ui.item.tipoVehi);
    }
});
```

Pero si yo genero el script antes no lo detecta y esto se debe porque el DOM no los reconoce

### Posible solución

```
$(document).on('autocomplete', '.searchInput', function (e) { });
```

Intente usar este método pero me marcar un error o simplemente no hace nada.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para aprender como funciona este sitio.  Te acabo de dar una respuesta, ya me dirás si es correcta para tu pregunta, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Diria que casi lo tenias. Prueba con esto:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '#placa', function() {
  $('#placa').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      console.log("Entre");
      $.ajax({
        url: "{{route('AjaxAlianza.getVehiculo')}}",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          term: request.term
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          response(data)
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      $('#idVehiculo').val(ui.item.idVehiculo);
      $('#marca').val(ui.item.marcaVehi);
      $('#modelo').val(ui.item.modeloVehi);
      $('#tipo').val(ui.item.tipoVehi);
    }
  });
});
```

**Explicación**

Mediante el [manejador de eventos `.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) de jquery capturamos el evento `keydown` del elemento con id **placa** y entonces podemos llamar al **autocomplete** porque en ese momento seguro que ya existe el elemento y su carga será correcta.

Es decir, cuando aparezca el *input* con id `placa` y empezemos a escribir en el, entonces el manejador de eventos se dará cuenta y ejecutará el código que contiene, que en este caso es el widget **[autocomplete](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)** de **jqueryui**.